# How to get they key and value of a LinkedHashMap randomly?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I'm trying to write a little vocabulary test. The LinkedHashMap `vocabulary` consists of vocabulary. They key is a french word and the value is an english word. I already have a GUI but I'm struggling to get a random french word from the vocabulary and its position to find out if the entered word is right. I tried to do it with an ArrayList but then I only get the value but I also need the key to show which word the person has to translate. Any help is appreciated.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> vocabulary = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    Random random = new Random();
    int number = random.nextInt(ReadExcelFile.lastRowNumber);
    String value = (new ArrayList<String>(vocabulary.values())).get(number);
```

Comment: You use `ReadExcelFile.lastRowNumber` as boundary for your index access. Consider to be careful about such things. Once you filled your data structure, why does it matter where the data was coming from? Instead: any collection in java can tell you about the number of elements it has. So: simply ask your map for its key set, and then use the size of that.

Comment: You can shuffle the list `Collections.shuffle(arrayList);` after collecting in an arraylist, get the item sequentially as the random.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the *keys* into a list, then pick a random one:

```
// Do once after loading (or changing)
List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<>(vocabulary.keySet());

Random random = new Random();
int number = random.nextInt(vocabulary.size());
String key = keyList.get(number);
String value = vocabulary.get(key);
```

Comment: Maybe better to store the new ArrayList in a new variable once at the beginning instead of each time generating a new one. If you plan to load all french words this operation may become slow.

Comment: @Conffusion I aimed for minimal code, but you are quite right. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can go in the following way!

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("Bonjour", "Hello");
myMap.put("moi", "me");
myMap.put("tue", "you");
        
List<String> val = new ArrayList<String>(myMap.values());
int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(val.size());
String randomValue = val.get(randomIndex);
            
System.out.println(randomValue);
```

Comment: OP wants the key and the value. Values may not be unique (two French words can both translate to the same English word), so this won’t work if you use OP’s map of String to String. However, you’ve used a map of String to Integer - could you explain what that’s for?

Comment: I agree with @Bohemian, looks like the same code as OP to me, but instead of String values, you changed to Integer. May I be missing something?

Comment: Yes @Bohemian made changes